# Typescript error when trying to setState based on previous state in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Hey I'm pretty new to typescript and I have a piece of state that I'm trying to alter in a child component based on the previous value but, I keep getting a type error when calling the setState function.

This is the function type

```
setPlayerCounts?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number[]>>;
```

This is where I'm getting an error on the parameter of setPlayerCounts

```
if(setPlayerCounts && playerCount !== undefined)
      setPlayerCounts(prev => prev ? [...prev, playerCount] : [playerCount]);
```

Error:

```
Argument of type '(prev: number[]) => (number | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number[]>'.

Type '(prev: number[]) => (number | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: number[]) => number[]'.\n    Type '(number | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.    
 
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.    
   
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.",
}]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can prev possibly be undefined?

Comment: Hello, do you have any reproducible code sample with your issue? Like code snippet, codesandbox?

Comment: how do you assign `playerCount`?

Comment: Change definition to `setPlayerCounts?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number[] | undefined>>;`

Answer (score 1):

```
setPlayerCounts(prev => [...(prev ?? []), playerCount!]);
```

Comment: Thank You! Can I ask what that bang(!) operator does at the end of playerCount? because that's what fixed the error

Comment: The (!) operator will force to no undefined type. ! is not null assertion operator.

Comment: Do take note that non-null assertion doesn't change the runtime behaviour, if `playerCount` is `null` or `undefined` during runtime and your code doesn't handle it, you might still run into problems.